# JAXB: Can we access and assign the inner node tags in the parent class using jaxb unmarshaller

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Below is the xml that I have which i wanted to convert to an object using JAXB unmarshaller:

```
<start>
    <name>sss</name>
    <address>
        <street1>xxx</street1>
        <street2>yyy</street2>
        <zip>121212</zip>
    </address>
</start>
```

Is there a possibility to access and set the zip in the start class?
Below is the root class for the above xml, for readability i am not completing the setters and getters:

```
pacakge com.data

//importing packages
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement; 

//Root element class declaration
@XmlRootElement(name="start")
public class Start {
    //elements that are in the xml
    private String name;
    private Address address;
    private int zip;

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    //setters and getters for name tag

    @XmlElement(name="address")
    //setters and getters for address tag

    @XmlElement(name="zip")
    //setters and getters for zip tag       
    public int getZip(){
        return zip;
    }
    public void setZip(int zip){
        this.zip = zip;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using EclipseLink and @XmlPath annotation